# Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using a Journal's format, however, receiving the following error:

> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year
>   citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers.

How to get rid of this? The header of the LaTeX file is copied below for ready reference.

```
\documentclass[graybox, natbib, nosecnum]{svmult}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,} % suppress commas between author-names and year
%\pdfoutput=1   %forces use of pdflatex. Disable if you prefer to use .eps 
or .ps figures.
% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide

\usepackage{mathptmx}       % selects Times Roman as basic font
\usepackage{helvet}         % selects Helvetica as sans-serif font
\usepackage{courier}        % selects Courier as typewriter font
\usepackage{type1cm}        % activate if the above 3 fonts are
                            % not available on your system

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                         % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for strike-through of text with \sout{}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  %for hyperlinks
\usepackage{soul}   % for high-lighting of text

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{99.}
% Book Chapter 
\bibitem{science-contrib} Broy, M.: Software engineering  from auxiliary to 
key technologies. In: Broy, M., Denert,
E. (eds.) Software Pioneers, pp. 10-13. Springer, New York (2002)
%
% Online Document
\bibitem{science-online} Cartwright, J.: Big stars have weather too. IOP 
Publishing PhysicsWeb.
\url{http://physicsweb.org/articles/news/11/6/16/1} (2007). Accessed 26 June 
2007
%
% Journal article
\bibitem{science-journal} Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and 
duality for nonlinear systems of partial
differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura. Appl. 169, 321-354 (1995)
%
% Journal article by DOI
\bibitem{science-DOI} Slifka, M.K., Whitton, J.L.: Clinical implications of 
dysregulated cytokine production. J. Mol. Med. (2000) doi: 
10.1007/s001090000086 
%
% Monograph
\bibitem{science-mono} Geddes, K.O., Czapor, S.R., Labahn, G.: Algorithms 
for Computer Algebra. Kluwer, Boston (1992) 
%
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document class you employ automatically loads the `natbib` citation management package. There's also clearly a presumption that bibtex will be employed to create the bibliography. However, you're building the bibliography by hand. This implies, among other things, that *you* are in charge of every single aspect of what goes on inside the `thebibliography` environment.

In the process of building each formatted bibliographic item using BibTeX, `natbib` structures the header of each `\bibitem` in a very specific way, so that its `\citet` and `\citep` instructions may find the information they need to create correctly-formatted citation call-outs. If you build the `thebibliography` environment by hand, while still loading the `natbib` package, you must replicate this structure or -- as you've discovered -- be inundated by lots of warning and/or error messages, as well as be left with unusable citation call-outs.

Here are three suggestions for how you might proceed.

1. Don't load `natbib`, i.e., comment out (or delete) the option `natbib` and the `\bibpunct` instruction. Clearly, this is the lazy way. Note that this approach will generate numeric-style citation call-outs, which your journal may or may not accept.
2. Rewrite the headers of each `\bibitem` list item. E.g., instead of

   ```
   \bibitem{science-contrib} Broy, M.: ...
   ...
   \bibitem{science-DOI} Slifka, M.K., Whitton, J.L.: ...
   ```

   write

   ```
   \bibitem[Broy(2002)]{science-contrib} Broy, M.
   ...
   \bibitem[Slifka and Whitton(2000)]{science-DOI} Slifka, M.K., Whitton, J.L.: ...
   ```

   As I hope you have guessed by now, the material in square brackets is read by `natbib` in order to create authoryear-style citation call-outs to the entries with keys `science-contrib` and `science-DOI`.
3. Learn how to use BibTeX. In the medium to longer run, you'll save yourself a huge amount of time and effort. Concentrate on writing your papers, and delegate to BibTeX the task of creating properly and consistently-formatted bibliographies. You, and the readers of your papers, will benefit.