# Author year citation style with manually created \bibitem entries

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

Is it possible to use `natbib`'s citation commands (citep and citet) and an author-year citation call-out style while building each `\bibitem` manually inside the main tex file?

The template I using for a journal submission does not allow external reference files

Edit: Following the sugestion os @Mico I managed to make the citep work but citet are not right:

```
As explained in (author?) (Keele et al. 2007), these set of guidelines (...)
```

Comment: Did you see [this query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414018/5001) and, in particular, [this associated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414044/5001)? The answer shows how one might build each `\bibitem` by hand while preserving the ability to create authoryear-style citation call-outs with the help of the citation commands of the `natbib` package.

Comment: I had not seen it, thanks @Mico . The second suggestion worked very well for me, although the third suggestion was the most correct one to make, I'm in a hurry to make it work.