# Trying to get natbib to compile with "numbers"

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

So okay at the start we have

```
\setcitestyle{numbers,aysep={,},yysep={;},notesep={, }}
```

and a typical bibliography entry is

```
\bibitem{Boolos1971}
\newblock{George Boolos, 1971},
\newblock{The iterative conception of set},
\newblock{\em{Journal of Philosophy}},
\newblock{vol. 68, Issue 8, pp. 215--231.}
```

and that works fine but if we change "numbers" to "square" in the first line of code then we get the error message "Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations" and "l.81 ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers".

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. Incidentally, since you're requesting numeric-style citation call-outs, setting values for `aysep` ("separation between author and year blocks") and `yysep` ("separation between consecutive year blocks") doesn't have an effect.

Comment: My bibliography begins with "\begin{thebibliography}{99}" and ends with "\end{thebibliography}", and I have "\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{numbers,aysep={,},yysep={;},notesep={, }}" near the start of my code, and I have given one example of how a bibliography entry is constructed, and I cannot find anything else relevant to the bibliography in the code except for use of \cite. Does that clarify sufficiently?

Comment: Are you saying that you built the bibliography by hand?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Since you've built the bibliography by hand, virtually all of the information you've provided so far is *simply irrelevant*. If you remove the `\newblock` "wrappers", you don't even need to load the `natbib` package. Do please replace `\em{Journal of Philosophy}` with `\emph{Journal of Philosophy}`, though.

Comment: See also [Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. …mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414018/5001).